# Handling SSH Keys for Multiple Users on Terraform-managed AWS EC2 SSH Bastion Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform, user-management

I have a stack of AWS infrastructure managed with Terraform. There is an EC2 SSH Bastion instance used by multiple users to access private ephemeral EC2 instances that are used for a variety of batch processing tasks.

Terraform provides a mechanism to include a single SSH key to an EC2 instance on creation, however I am trying to find a solution, preferably but not necessarily Terraform-based, that would allow the management of multiple users for the SSH Bastion.

Is there a solution allowing the SSH Bastion to use the SSH keys associated with IAM users such that when (for example) `bob` attempts to SSH to the Bastion, the Bastion can use the public key associated with `bob` should `bob` belong to the correct group, have the correct permission, have the right tag, or some other identifying feature?

And if the above question implies the wrong approach to the problem, is there a better way to look at and solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would need to create the users and add the respective keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` you could bake this into the AMI (with eg [Packer](https://www.packer.io/)) or you could do this via user-data or even with a Terraform provisioner. There isn't, however, a way for you to spin up an instance and directly say to add users and keys for them like can be done with [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#vm-creation-ssh)

Comment: I can't bake the SSH keys into the AMI, since users will be added and removed from the AWS account, or granted and revoked access to this system. Rebuilding the Bastion AMI each time that happens and rebuilding the infra for that doesn't make sense.

There must be some sane way to relate IAM users with certain permissions to allow SSH access to the Bastion.

Comment: There is but Terraform can't manage it for you because AWS doesn't expose it as an API. The answer would be to run Ansible/Chef/Puppet against the bastion every time you want to change the users or keys on the box. Or to have the box automatically pull down a list of users and keys and configure it itself. If you put it into the AMI or user data then Terraform will need to replace each time it changes.

Comment: In general though you might want to consider an alternative option such as [EC2 instance connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html) or [SSM Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html).

Comment: It sounds like, no matter which way I go, I'll need to step outside of a pure Terraform solution. EC2 Instance Connect has some promise, but I suspect the sane approach there is to drop the Bastion entirely and allow users to go directly to their EC2 instances doing the batch processing (which is what the Bastion is allowing access to). And that is a different can of worms, including running out of Elastic IPs.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand this right you are asking 2 questions here:

Q1. Is there a way to automatically add users to a bastion and set their ssh credentials?

Yes you can do that with a userdata script that will run during the ec2 creation time.

The script should add the users.
Assuming you run linux on you bastion server the snippet to add users would be something like

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash <username>
mkdir /home/<username>/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/<username>/.ssh/


Copy the ssh key from a pre-determined location. In my case i have ssh 
public keys for users in an S3 bucket (hey they are public keys)
aws s3 cp s3://path/pub-keys/user-id_rsa.pub /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys

chmod 640 /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R <username>:<group> /home/<username>/.ssh/

Add the user to some group
usermod -a -G <somegroup> <username>
```

Q2. Can AWS IAM credentials be used for ssh on some sort of single sign on?
For this I'd recommend to read the documentation below as there are several things involved, including the distribution you are using. But I am not sure this is a good solution for the scenario you described.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html

Comment: Your assessment is roughly correct, however the end goal is some way where the Bastion takes the public SSH keys associated with IAM users and uses them as authorized users, and when those IAM users or keys change, that's reflected in real time on the Bastion. I wish to avoid rebuilding the AMI every time there's a user change, or managing the public keys through scripts and S3 (which is what you suggested, and something I've thought about doing). However it seems that EC2 Instance Connect or similar may be the only sane way to meet most of the goals.

Comment: I initially misunderstood your question and thought the bastions where ephemeral that's why I suggested having the "userdata" script. Unfortunately I can't see a way to do it with terraform, i think you will have to go for the EC2 Instance Connect or use a config management tool, like ansible.
You could also try the aws cli and run some script on the bastion that gets the keys from the IAM, but again that would be a script.
Another idea that crosses my mind is that you distribute the keys when you create them, if you use some automation in place for creating the keys it would be easy.

Comment: If the Bastions were ephemeral that would make it easier, yes. Apologies for the lack of clarity. It does appear that the way I wish to solve the problem is not realistic so I'll have to find another way. Potentially having no Bastion at all, and using something akin to EC2 Direct Connect for users to attach directly to their ephemeral batch instances, is the solution.

Comment: No, I apologise for misreading your question. I was reading your other comments and if you just use the bastion as a jump host, why don't you create a VPN in AWS and allow direct access to the EC2 Instances. With the VPN you can keep the IPs private and you don't really need the bastion. But to be honest your initial problem is far more interesting :)

Comment: Haha, agreed, the initial problem is more interesting, but I'll take simple over interesting any day of the week. :-) Perhaps the VPN solution (or something similar, such a public subnet that only allows traffic to and from a set of IP addresses under our control) is the way to go.